# Valid gzip file contains a large block of NULL bytes - why?

Tags: compression, gzip, deflate

I have a tar.gz file which contains large blocks of NULL bytes (>1kb). The archive seems to be valid (checked via `gzip -t <file-name>`) and extraction works properly without issues.

The NULL byte blocks are somewhat in the middle of the file. Therefore, I don't think this is related to padding.

Is this expected? What would cause gzip to write this many NULL bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very long sequence of the same byte repeated can result in the output being a sequence of zero bytes. Though there will be about 1/1000th as many zero bytes in the compressed output as there are repeated bytes in the input.

Comment: More precisely, the ratio is 1/1032.